# Impossible to boot on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, grub

I tried an installation of Linux Mint 20.1 in dual boot with Windows 10 with a flash drive.  My laptop is an asus R510V with an i5-6300HQ, 4GB of RAM and Intel HD graphics 530.

It looks like the installation has worked since half of my disk space has disappeared from my Windows partition (the proportion I specified when installing mint) but I can't launch Mint when booting. I don't have the GRUB option I am supposed to choose.

Answer (score 0):

Common bootloader-not-changed-to-GRUB problem. If you are using UEFI, make sure you made a `/boot/efi` partition when you installed Mint and enter BIOS and set boot order to Mint first.

If it is a MBR use `sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sdX` after booting and chrooting from the flash to write GRUB launcher in bootstarp area of the disk.

If you missed the EFI setup part, boot in the live media, make a partiton of more or less 512 MB, format it FAT,  mark as bootable, chroot, mount it and run `sudo grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/path/to/mounted/partition --bootloader-id=GRUB`